# Solve the recurrence $T\left(n\right)\:=\:3T\left(n-1\right)\:+\:3n^2$

Tags: recurrence-relation, discrete-mathematics, mathematical-analysis

I am trying to solve the recurrence

$T\left(n\right)\:=\:3T\left(n-1\right)\:+\:3n^2$

I tried method I saw but I do not fully understand which looks like:

$T\left(n-1\right)\:=\:3T\left(n-2\right)\:+\:3\left(n-1\right)^2$

$T\left(n\right)\:=\:3\left[3T\left(n-2\right)\:+\:3\left(n-1\right)^2\right]\:+\:3n^2$

$T\left(n\right)\:=\:3\left[3(3T\left(n−3\right)+3\left(n−2\right)^2)\:+\:3\left(n-1\right)^2\right]\:+\:3n^2$

But I am not sure if this is the right way and how do I continue.

Answer (score 1):

Let $S(n) = T(n)/3^n$. Then
$$
S(n) = \frac{T(n)}{3^n} = \frac{T(n-1)}{3^{n-1}} + \frac{3n^2}{3^n} = S(n-1) + \frac{n^2}{3^{n-1}}.
$$
You take it from here.

Comment: I am not sure how to take it from here

Comment: I'm sorry, you'll have to work it out. Try harder.

Comment: It looks almost the same as the problem before for me in terms of what should I do with this kind of equations, so I don't even know how try try harder, what should I look at

Comment: You can get an explicit formula for $S(n)$ by unrolling the recurrence. You get a sum, which you can either estimate as $O(1)$, as in Steven's answer, or compute exactly, say using Wolfram alpha.

Answer (score 1):

You can continue unrolling the recurrence until you see the pattern, and you are able to write a general formula. Then instantiate it in a way that results in writing $T(n)$ as a function of the base case (which I'm going to assume being $T(1)=1$).

$$
\begin{align*}
T(n) &= 3 \cdot T(n-1)+ 3n^2   \\
T(n) &= 3^2 \cdot T(n-2) + 3^2(n-1)^2 + 3n^2 \\
T(n) &= 3^3 \cdot T(n-3) + 3^3 (n-2)^2+ 3^2(n-1)^2 + 3n^2 \\
& \vdots \\
T(n) &= 3^i \cdot T(n-i) + \sum_{j=1}^{i} 3^j (n-j+1)^2. \tag{*}
\end{align*}
$$

Therefore, choosing $i=n-1$:
$$
T(n) = 3^{n-1} \cdot T(1) + \sum_{j=1}^{n-1} 3^j (n-j+1)^2 = 3^{n-1}  + 3^{n+1} \sum_{j=2}^{n} 3^{-j} \cdot j^2.
$$

Since $\sum_{j=2}^{n} 3^{-j} \cdot j^2 \le \sum_{j=2}^{\infty} 3^{-j} \cdot j^2$, and the latter series is convergent, you have $T(n)=\Theta(3^n)$.

Notice that the above argument involves some "magic" dots, where you are claiming that after unrolling the recursion $i$ times you get $(*)$. To get a formal proof you need to proceed by induction.

Answer (score 0):

Now, **Initial Conditions** of Recurrence Relation are **not** given.

Still, We can use [**Master Theorem**](https://ediscretestructures.blogspot.com/2022/03/master-theorem-for-recurrence-relation.html) to find asymptotic bound of given recurrence relation without any initial condition(s).

*(For **Solving the Recurrence Relation**, we need **initial conditions**, which are **not** mentioned in problem)*

If a **Recurrence Relation** is of the Form

### $$T(n)=aT\big(n-b\big)+{f(n)}$$

Then, as per [**Master Theorem**](https://ediscretestructures.blogspot.com/2022/03/master-theorem-for-recurrence-relation.html#:%7E:text=FOR%20DECREASING%20FUNCTIONS%C2%A0), we have **Three Conditions** depending on value of $a$

- If $a=1$
  Answer is $O(nf(n))$
- If $a>1$
  Answer is $O(a^{\frac{n}{b}}f(n))$
- If $a<1$
  Answer is $O(f(n))$

In any problem, our main motive is to find $a, f(n)$ and $b$. Moreover we can replace $f(n)$ by it's asymptotic equivalent.

**In Given Problem**

- $a=3$
- $b=1$
- $f(n)=n^2$

Now, $a>1$
Therefore, Answer is $O(3^{n}n^2)$

### $$O(3^{n}n^2)$$

Comment: The conditions you state cannot possibly be true. Consider $T(n)=T(n-1) + 2^n$, with $T(1)=2$. Then $a=1$ and $b=1$ but we have $T(n) = \sum_{i=1}^n 2^i = 2^{i+1} - 2 \not\in \Theta(n 2^n)$.

Comment: @Steven, The summation will be equal to $2^{n+1}-2$, which does belongs to $O(n2^n)$. The $\Theta$ has been replaced by $O$

Comment: @RohitSingh How does it appeal when $f\left(n\right)\:=\:logn$ ?

Comment: It will be $O(3^{n}logn)$. Please note that $f(n)$ need **not** to be a polynomial function.

Comment: I am afraid I didn't get what you meant by not to be a polynomial function. In first question for example, is $3n^2$ not a polynom? for a=2, b=0, c=0 for example @RohitSingh

Comment: $f(n)$ can be a polynomial function, like $3n^2$, or cannot be a polynomial function, like $\log n$. In **both the cases, we can apply [Master Theorem](http://cs.uok.edu.in/Files/79755f07-9550-4aeb-bd6f-5d802d56b46d/Custom/Ten%20Master%20Method.pdf)**

Now, for $a=2, b=0,$ and $c=0$, it doesn't make any sense. It means $T(n)$ depends on $2T(n)$, which is illogical. Moreover, no term was labelled as $c$ in this **Master Theorem**

Comment: @RohitSingh I guess I was not clear enough, my bad. You said "Please note that f(n) need not to be a polynomial function." English is not my first language, So I read this as, in other words: f(n) Can not be a polynomial function. So I asked how the term applied when $3n^2$ is a polynom with a=2,b=0,c=0 (for ax^2 +bx +c). But as I read your other response I get the impression that f(n) can be anything, polynomial or not polynomial.

Comment: @RohitSingh By the way, I don't know if it is allowed but can I get a reference for this way you have shown me? I didn't knew this way and it seems interesting I would like to read about it more.